# CSS drop down sub menu disappears when using Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble with following site in IE9.  As you may notice the sub menu disappears as the mouse hovers over.

vinehousefarm-farmshop.co.uk

HTML:

http://pastebin.com/JUWsGyFM

CSS:

http://pastebin.com/yEq8MCwM

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the margin-top:4px on your li. It causes the cursor to loose focus on the anchor element. You better use padding-top on your anchors in the submenu.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, much appreciated!!